# fluent query for the following scenario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a list of programs in the database. Each program has an `organization_id` to which the program belongs to, plus a `start_date` and `end_date`.

My question is, how should the query look like if two dates are given and i have to get all the programs that start between the dates or end between the dates for a specific organization. the following query returns all programs that are beyond the organization scope (not belonging to an organization).

```
<?php

DB::table('programs')
    ->where('organization_id', $organizationidlist[0])
    ->whereBetween('start_date', array($start_date, $end_date))
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use($start_date, $end_date, $organizationidlist) {
        $query
            ->where('organization_id', $organizationidlist[0])
            ->whereBetween('end_date', array($start_date, $end_date))
        ;
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this with eloquent models?  Laravel has such a nice data model system.  You could easily do what you want with something like:

```
Organization::find($id)->projects()->where('start_date', '>', $start)->where('end_date', '<', $end)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent